# datatable tables[0] error "Cannot find table 0" when using JOIN

Tags: c#, oracle, datagrid, system.data

I know this has been asked a lot before, but in this case I think it has something to do with using `JOIN` in the query, because I've run the exact same code with a simple `SELECT` statement and its always returned a table, AND I've checked the `JOIN` query in the sqlplus command line and there's always a result, so it's not a problem with the query itself

The method is:

```
        public static DataView method()
    {
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        db.Connect();

        db.SetSql("select column1, column2, column3 from table1 natural join table2");

        DataSet result = db.RetrieveRecords();

        DataView source = new DataView(result.Tables[0]);

        db.Dispose();

        return source;
    }
```

I use the same method to populate a different datagrid in the application, the only difference is the query in `db.SetSql`, which is `select column1, column2 from table1`. That datagrid is always populated fine, and even if the query result is 0 rows, it just shows the grid empty and doesn't throw an error.

Like I said, the `JOIN` query gives a result in the command line, but when I run my application, the "Cannot find table 0" error is thrown at the line `DataView source = new DataView(result.Tables[0]);`

Is it possibly something like when you use `JOIN` the result is not considered a table?

The code for `DBConnection.RetrieveRecords()`:

```
public DataSet RetrieveRecords()
    {
        OracleDataAdapter DataAdapter = null;
        DataSet result = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            command.Connection = connection;   //command is OracleCommand and connection is OracleConnection
            DataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            DataAdapter.Fill(result);
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            autoDisconnect = true;
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        //Cleaning
        finally
        {
            if (command.Parameters.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (OracleParameter pram in command.Parameters)
                {
                    pram.Dispose();
                }
            }
            if (command != null)
            {
                command.Dispose();
            }
            if (DataAdapter != null)
            {
                DataAdapter.Dispose();
            }
            if (autoDisconnect)
            {
                Dispose();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And `DBConnection.SetSql()` (if it matters):

```
    public void SetSql(string sql)
    {
        command = new OracleCommand(sql);
        command.BindByName = true;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried "normal" join, i.e. specifying column names rather than the "fancy" natural join?

Comment: @IvanStoev, you mean `FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.column1 = table2.column1`? I will try, but if natural join worked when querying directly, why wouldn't it from an application? It's going to the same database

Comment: That's true, but when you don't know what's going on, you need to start  eliminating every possible thing you can think of. Especially with Oracle - I guess you are using ODP.NET provider.